# Https reqest to get Gift card balance with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, request

I want to build a balance checker for Paysafecards for my own site. (JavaScript and HTML) https://www.paysafecard.com/en/balance-check/ has the function that i would need, but i want the function on my own site.

I testet a little bit with Codex and the best was this:

```
var paysafecard = document.createElement('div');
paysafecard.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="paysafecard" placeholder="Enter your PaysafeCard PIN" />';
paysafecard.innerHTML += '<button id="checkBalance">Check Balance</button>';
paysafecard.innerHTML += '<div id="balance"></div>';
document.body.appendChild(paysafecard);
document.getElementById('checkBalance').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var pin = document.getElementById('paysafecard').value;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.paysafecard.com/en/balance-check/' + pin, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      var balance = xhr.responseText.match(/<span class="amount">(.*?)<\/span>/);
      if (balance) {
        document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = 'Balance: ' + balance[1];
      } else {
        document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = 'Invalid PIN';
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
});
```

but it dosent really work.

Comment: Looks like a way to steal others' pins, assuming you could get it to work.

Comment: its for an site im building, where you can buy things with your remaining credit.